# Checking the payment status from an payment APi

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, paystack

Am trying to verify user transaction on paystack. After a user  makes payment, I want what to append the reference to the Api URL to check if the payment was succcessful. If the payment is successful then  save the model.

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings


class Paystack:
    PAYSTACK_SECRET_KEY = "sk_test_3cd83d64a1de3a7334bdad47e3fdfa01bf16a059"
    base_url = "https://api.paystack.co"

    def verify_payment(self, reference, *args, **kwargs):
        path = f'/transaction/verify/{reference}'

        headers ={
              "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.PAYSTACK_SECRET_KEY}",
              "Content-Type":'application/json'
        }
        url = self.base_url + path
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
              response_data = response.json()
              return response_data['status'], response_data['data']
        response_data = response.json()
        return response_data["status"], response_data["message"]
```

```
def process_payment(request, slug, amount, award, votes):
    reason = request.GET.get('reason')
    transaction_id = request.GET.get('reference')
    amount = (str(int(amount) / 100))
    paystack = Paystack()
    status = paystack.process_payment(self.reference)
    if status == "success":
        transaction = SuccessfulTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount,
            award=award
        )
        transaction.save()
        Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + votes)
        Award.objects.filter(slug=award).update(amount=F('amount') + amount)
        return redirect('vote:paymentsuccess', slug=slug)
    else:
        context = {
            'error': reason
        }
        transaction = FailedTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount,
            award=award
        )
        transaction.save()
        return render(request, 'payment_error.html', context=context)
```

This is the eeror i get

```
AttributeError at /payment/Paul/000000000020/halotech-award-8/1/

'Paystack' object has no attribute 'process_payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

verify_payment vs process_payment.

```
    def verify_payment(self, reference, *args, **kwargs):
```

```
    status = paystack.process_payment(self.reference)
```